# Using utf8mb4 for smilies in Grails 3 with MySQL 5.5.42

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, utf8mb4

I want to save smilies from an iOS App in a MySQL database via a Grails 3 backend. 
So far I managed to change my MySQL collation etc. to utf8mb4 but I did not find the correct way how to connect my backend to MySQL via utf8mb4 charset.

My connection url was:

```
development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: "update"
        url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mydbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true"
```

Changing the characterEncoding or charset to "utf8mb4" does lead to an error: "Unsupported character encoding 'utf8mb4'."

My grails connector in the build.gradle is "runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'"

So what do I have to change in my dataSource url?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems I finally found the solution:

Just remove the "characterEncoding=UTF" part in the dataSource url. Otherwise grails always forces MySQL to use UTF-8 instead of utf8mb4.
E.g.

```
dataSource:
        dbCreate: "update"
        url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mydbname?useUnicode=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true"
```